# How to deploy jHipster on Azure App Service, I got 500 request timed out

Tags: azure, spring-boot, deployment, jhipster, azure-web-app-service

This guideline provided by Microsoft is for SpringBoot App

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-spring-boot-web-app-on-azure

which is essentially:

1. Create an Azure web app for use with Java
2. Specify the Java version
3. Obtain FTP deployment credential
4. Upload your SpringBoot .JAR along with provided web.config
5. Restart the web app via Azure portal
6. The app works!

Instead of `.jar`, jHipster is producing `.war` file. Since it is essentially the same (i.e. it can be executed with `java -jar`), I was hoping the steps would also works for `.war`.

I've uploaded:

1. the `.war` file
2. the `.war.original` file
3. `web.config`

This is the aforementioned `web.config`. Please note I've renamed the -jar into -war

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
        arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -war &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\gmbgenpro-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war&quot;">
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The app is loading so long that I got the `500 request timed out.`

EDIT: I've enabled `stdout` in the web.config and I got the following from the log files:

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: -war
```

So it seems I could not use the -war parameter, and I don't know what to do.

Comment: No, I did not set anything in `application.yml`, only on `application-prod.yml` for the database. 
Now that I look at the `application.yml`, Where should I put this `spring.profiles.active` parameter? I see no web.xml on the folder.
As for the log file, I've edited my post.

Comment: I've tried deploying the .war file on `wwwroot/webapps/` and renamed the file as ROOT.war. It still doesn't work. I got `HTTP Status 404 – Not Found`

Comment: -war is not an option for Java (like the error says).  Try with -jar instead.  That is how is described in http://www.jhipster.tech/production/

Comment: There's now an official doc at https://www.jhipster.tech/azure/

Answer (score 1):

To deploy your JHipster project as a WAR file, make sure you build it with `spring-boot.repackage.skip` option enabled. This will skip building an executable WAR file and simply package the WAR file normally under ${finalName}.war. This way you can deploy your application to a web runtime on Azure automatically configured for you.

To proceed with the deployment, follow these steps:

1. Add the following Maven Plugin configuration to your main  element of your pom.xml:

   ```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <!-- check Maven Central for the latest version -->
        <version>1.3.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <resourceGroup>your-resource-group</resourceGroup>
            <appName>your-app-name</appName>
            <linuxRuntime>tomcat 9.0-jre8</linuxRuntime>-->
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
   ```
2. Build your project with the following command, and adjust your profile accordingly:

   ```
   ./mvnw clean package -Pdev -Dspring-boot.repackage.skip=true
   ```
3. Deploy your application:

   ```
   ./mvnw azure-webapp:deploy
   ```

For up-to-date information about the Maven Plugin for Azure App Service, check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/maven/azure-webapp-maven-plugin/readme?WT.mc_id=online-jhipster-brborges).